# what windows policy settings are minimally required to get true/false response from isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()

Tags: windows, group-policy, browser

In a corporate setting there are Windows Group Policies restricting the use of FIDO Platform authenticators (e.g. Windows Hello (for Business) on Microsoft Windows devices)

Using the `PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()` method in a browser results in `false` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PublicKeyCredential/isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable_static).

Is there any clear approach on **which Windows Group Policy settings need to be enabled/set exactly** to get a true response?

Second, which policies would be required to make the FIDO/WebAuthN platform authenticator work, if that would be different/further policies.

If possible, **we don't need users to rollout for Windows Hello for Business or have that active**, but they should be able to pair their device as a FIDO Platform authenticator for other online services/platforms, where that is a possible authentication method.

*Yes I can try it out but maybe there is a good explanation or somebody else already faced this issue (possibly in a corporate context with restricted/managed devices).*

Comment: `which policies would be required to make the FIDO/WebAuthN platform authenticator work?` Work? You need to be specific. Do you need it for logging on to the endpoint or to use with a web application?

Comment: First to get a `true` response from `PublicKeyCredential.isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()` (doesn't matter which of the mechanisms like biometrics/PIN/... are used, but to make any of them available to the browser as platform authenticator.

Comment: Can you provide the Windows versions you tested this on with a fresh install and it worked as expected? And not joined to a domain. (Group Policy only applies to a domain member).

Comment: A fresh install might work fine, I only have devices were it does not work. Those are corporate managed devies with group policies, I'd need to check which policies are set/not set. But that is the questions, which policies are interesting here ;)

Comment: A test on a fresh install not domain joined should be the first step.  Then the other variations. Fresh install, and domain joined. Existing endpoint switched to workgroup.

Comment: Yes that would be the approach to figure it out by trial and error until I have the policies identified. But I was hoping for someone already having that knowledge or better documentation. 
Anyway, if I figure it out I'll post it as answer.

Comment: I've seen several questions about this on Stack Overflow, may want to try there. Probably more usage there than a corporate environment, given the prevalence of other authenticators.